# how to sort a column by slash in sql server

Tags: sorting, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-order-by

I don't get how to sort or order by column that contains values as following

### abc/aa

### aa

### bb/cba

### bb/aa

### cc

Now I need the values in the column to be displayed as **the values containing slash to be displayed last and those that don't have slash to be displayed at first.**

### Required Output

### aa

### cc

### cba

### abc/aa

### bb/aa

### bb/cba

Please guide me

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide your query, but the form will be

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (CharVal VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @Tbl VALUES ('abc/aa'),('aa'),('bb/cba'),('bb/aa'),('cc')
SELECT CharVal FROM @Tbl
ORDER BY CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%/%',CharVal) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, CharVal
```

Output:
      CharVal
      aa
      cc
      abc/aa
      bb/aa
      bb/cba

EDIT: Corrected 0/1 reversal in the CASE statement that resulted in incorrect sort order, thanks @Aaron_Bertrand! Also added populating a temp table with the data and showing the output.